# Параллельный запуск python-selenium теста одновременно 50 раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите, можно ли реализовать Python - selenium тест который нужно запустить параллельно 50-100 раз. Задача сэмитировать одновременное присутствие 50-100 людей на сайте через python selenium-тесты.

Вот код:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
from threading import Thread

def start():
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
    capabilities['marionette'] = False
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
    driver.get('http://localhost:8085/')
    time.sleep(1)
    fild_pass = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='passphrase']")
    fild_pass.clear()
    fild_pass.send_keys("111111111")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/button[1]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/a").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/button").click()
    seed = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='textarea-block']/textarea").text
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/button").click()

        #-------------    reeestration  ----------------------

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/ul/li[3]/label").click()
    fil = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='auth-seed']/div/textarea")
    fil.clear()
    fil.send_keys(seed)
    time.sleep(0.4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='auth-seed']/button").click()
    time.sleep(0.4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/button[1]").click()
    time.sleep(10)


    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='dashboard']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='dashboard']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[3]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    array_wallet = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='walletTab']/div[2]/div/div")
    try:
        for i in array_wallet:
            print(i.text)
            i.click()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            for i in array_wallet[:1:-1]:
                print(i.text)
                i.click()
                time.sleep(0.5)
    except Exception as e:
           print(e)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='top-panel']/div[2]").click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # --------------- e-login--------------
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='dashboard']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='dashboard']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div[3]").click()
    mass = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div")
    for i in mass:
        i.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/button[1]").click()
        time.sleep(3)


    #------------------- etherdelta -----------------
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='top-panel']/div[2]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='dashboard']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='dashboard']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div[3]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-5']/ul/li[1]").click()
    amount = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='et-5-deposit']")
    amount.clear()
    amount.send_keys("0")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-5-1']/div/button[1]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    ethamount = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='et-5-ethAmount']")
    ethamount.clear()
    ethamount.send_keys("0")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-5-1']/div/button[2]").click()
    #---------------
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-5']/ul/li[2]").click()
    witham = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='et-5-widthdraw']")
    witham.clear()
    witham.send_keys("0")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-5-2']/div/button[1]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    ethwith = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='et-5-ethAmount-withdraw']")
    ethwith.clear()
    ethwith.send_keys("0")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-5-2']/div/button[2]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #---------------
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-2']/ul/li[1]").click()
    buy1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='et-currency-buy']")
    buy1.clear()
    buy1.send_keys("0")
    buy2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='et-amount-buy']")
    buy2.clear()
    buy2.send_keys("0")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-2-1']/div/div/div/div[1]/button").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #--------------
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-2']/ul/li[2]").click()
    sel_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='et-currency']")
    sel_1.clear()
    sel_1.send_keys("0")
    sel_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='et-amount']")
    sel_2.clear()
    sel_2.send_keys("0")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-2-2']/div/div/div/div[1]/button").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #--------------
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/ul/li[1]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/ul/li[2]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/ul/li[3]").click()
    time.sleep(1)

    time.sleep(3)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Thread(target=start)
    p2 = Thread(target=start)
    p3 = Thread(target=start)
    p4 = Thread(target=start)
    p5 = Thread(target=start)
    p6 = Thread(target=start)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()
    p6.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    p5.join()
    p6.join()
```

Пытался запускать по всякому и через асинхронность и через потоки но ничего не получается. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: И что происходит, когда вы этот код запускаете?

Comment: Запускается 6 окон Firefox и начинает параллельно проходить всё описанное в функции. Тоесть коннект к сайту поднятому локально. Потом адрес локального хоста поменяется на адрес сайта. То есть делает то что нужно, но только в 6 потоков. Поэтому упёрся в полную загрузку проца. Максимум запускаю 20 потоков и всё. Если больше то комп не вытягивает. А надо 50-100 хотя бы.

Comment: Вообще, селениум не используют для нагрузки. Попробуйте специализированное ПО. Например, JMeter. С селениум можно попробовать хедлесс режим (когда окно браузера не отображается) или браузер PantomJS. Возможно, больше получится потоков

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Увы специализированное ПО не даёт полноценной имитации поведения пользователя(клац там, клац тут) и так далее. За режим хедлесс сейчас почитаю. Может даст плюс десяточку. Единственное, что смог сделать - это реализовать мультитрейдинг через асинхронность. Это на всякий случай если вдруг один из потоков вылетает, то другой становится на его место. При этом смог выжать 50 окон. Будет кому нужен код пишите. Правда он не оптимизирован ))